# Questions about whiptail and bash functions

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, whiptail

- Say I have this script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  function cpp-lang {  
  yum install "Development Tools"  
  }
  function updatesys { 
  yum -y update 
  yum -y upgrade
  }

       whiptail --checklist "test" 5 40 5\
                  Update "Update the system" on \
                  C++ "Install C++" off 2>results 

  while read choice 
  do
        case $choice in
          Update )updatesys
           ;;
          C++)cpp-lang
           ;;
           *)
           ;;
           esac
           done < results
  ```

  When I run it, it exits, should I return something from the function?
- Considering the script above as an example, should I run `sudo` every time I call `yum install` or is doing `sudo ./script.sh`enough?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Yes, [running `sudo script` is enough](http://askubuntu.com/a/425990/85695) (and recommended), don't run `sudo command` every time a command needs to be run as root.

Comment: @terdon okay, the main question is the second one, should I ask another question for the first one? - thanks for answering the last one

Comment: Yes, please ask the first one separately. The last was the only one I could answer :)

Comment: @terdon [done that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182039/resizing-whiptail-to-full-terminal-screen). Really? I thought my question is silly, I mean all I'm trying to do is to create a script that will let me install bunch of software that I usually Install on all my vps, so a nice whiptail screen and I select what I want. If you can't answer then my chances of getting an answer are slim :) usually when no one answers my linux questions I pray for Zeus of Kernels to let Tendron see it in order to solve the problem :P

Comment: Ha! Thanks, but I've never used whiptail so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically (the second question of course regarding the way `sudo` should be used most effectively), it's a matter of judgement:

- In the script there are three calls to `yum`.  If the script tested at the beginning whether it is running as **`root`** and sudo'd to run itself, that would make a simpler script.
- On the other hand, some people might comment that running exclusively as **`root`** makes it less safe to test the interactive part (in case you continued to develop and expand the script, including specifying the package names directly).  My own inclination would be to provide a command-line option to let the script be *tested*, and just show (or log) the corresponding commands that would be run.

For instance:

- what happens if `whiptail` is not installed?
- if `$choice` is not a word, it might help to quote it in the `case` statement.
- what happens if yum reports an error (does the user see that, or is there another call to `whiptail` later)?