# Resizing Whiptail to full terminal screen

Tags: bash, whiptail

How to make whiptail full terminal screen? "as big as the terminal", like fluid CSS, something like `100%`

Comment: [Related issue here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182021/questions-about-whiptail-and-bash-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
whiptail --msgbox hello $(stty -a | tr \; \\012 |
    egrep 'rows|columns' | cut '-d ' -f3)
```

Comment: exactly like that, could you please modify it slightly to make it work with my own script here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182021/questions-about-whiptail-and-bash-functions ? It's working but when I try to put it in my existing script, I get errors

Comment: If I substitute that `$(stty ...)` pipeline into the `whiptail` command you have over at that other question it works fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

`stty size` gives you all you need.  So for example:

`whiptail --msgbox test $(stty size)`